# RabbitMQ PHP AMQPConnection Discontinued, which alternative to use?

Tags: php, rabbitmq, legacy

The RabbitMQ PHP extension is gone as of now!
http://www.php.net/manual/en/amqpqueue.consume.php

making the install proces a bit ... impossible.

Seems like it was discontinued without being marked as deprecated or else what.

the official rabitMQ php library [php-amqplib](https://github.com/php-amqplib/php-amqplib) and its code structure is so abysmal that there is even an oop acess lib to acess a library:
https://github.com/thecodingmachine/oo-amqp-client

Anyone has a better alternative?
(to use a lib to Access another library which is a Implementation of an extension is not in mu bullpark)

Comment: "its code structure is so abysmal" - it is open source, by all means, contribute to it, rather than complain about the software you get **for free**.

Comment: When there are about 6 libraries that make the library more OOP (hint, most of the official links in http://www.rabbitmq.com/devtools.html for PHP are using this as a base and only abstracting the access) im guessing the maintainers do not rly care about usability. My main problem is the lack of documentation. I had to debug the code to figure out the wait function is the actual consumer and the consume function invokes a new consumer instance... and NOT the register consumer. If you replace the extension with this one, you are in for a nasty surprise.